# Getting scss parse error in running storybook on svelte

Tags: sass, svelte, storybook

Getting Parse error identifier expected when running storybook in svelte project

Tried installing @storybook/preset-scss, sass-loader, node-sass but still getting error like

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader/index.js):
Error: ParseError: Identifier is expected (204:4)
202:     position: relative;
203:
204:     .error-panel {
         ^
205:       position: absolute;
206:       bottom: 100%;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [svelte-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess) to use Sass inside a Svelte component. Install the package and add preprocess to the svelte-loader options.

```js
// webpack.config.js

// other imports
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
    // other properties
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svelte$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'svelte-loader',
                    options: {
                        // other svelte-loader options
                        preprocess: sveltePreprocess() // this will process sass inside a component
                    }
                }
            },
            // other loaders
        ]
    },
    // etc
};
```

You can then write Sass inside a component like so (note the `lang="scss"` attribute on the style tag).

```html
<main>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</main>

<style lang="scss">
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        h1 {
            color: green;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update based on `"@storybook/svelte": "^6.5.12",`

The `.storybook/main.cjs` should look like so

```
const { 
  typescript: preprocessTs, 
  scss: preprocessScss 
} = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|svelte)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-svelte-csf",
    "@storybook/preset-scss"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/svelte",
  "core": {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-vite"
  },
  "svelteOptions": {
    "preprocess": [
      preprocessTs(), // sveltekit-storybook typescript support
      preprocessScss() // sveltekit-storybook sass support
    ]
  },
  "features": {
    "storyStoreV7": true
  }
}
```

You can then write Sass inside a component like so (note the lang="scss" attribute on the style tag).

```
<main>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</main>

<style lang="scss">
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        h1 {
            color: green;
        }
    }
</style>
```